# when trying to update a newly created remote branch, I get "rejected"

Tags: git

This has happened to me several times now and I don't understand why, so I thought I'd ask...  This is basically what I do:

```
get fetch --all
git push origin my_new_branch

Counting objects: 68, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 6.68 KiB, done.
Total 43 (delta 34), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:FooBar/foobar.git
* [new branch]      my_new_branch -> my_new_branch
```

Then I realize..  Oops, I forgot to make sure my new branch is current with master..

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout my_new_branch
git rebase master
git push origin my_new_branch

To git@github.com:FooBar/foobar.git
 ! [rejected]        my_new_branch -> my_new_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:FooBar/foobar.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Why does this happen???  And more importantly, how can I make it not happen (other than doing -f and forcing it...)  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expected to force it with `-f`. That's what it's there for.

Git by default refuses to push a new value of a ref that is not descendant of the previous value. That's a safety measure. If somebody else based their work on the old ref and you rewind it, you are going to cause a lot of trouble for them (well, nothing that one could not handle, but they'd need to *know* about it).

If you need to quickly fix up a mistake, just go ahead, rebase and force the push. If it's your own branch that you push just to show it to somebody, but nobody is supposed to base their work on top of it and everybody know they are not supposed to, just go ahead, rebase and force the push. If you want to update the branch in any other way, merge, don't rebase.

Answer (score 0):

When you rebase a branch, some of the commits that constitute it are lost and new commits are re-made on top of branch on to which you are rebasing. This means that `rebase` doesn't preserve all of the history of a branch. When you push a branch, the head of the branch that you push must contain all of the history of the branch that you are replacing so that you don't lose any commits from the remote branch.

When you publish a branch you should avoid rebasing it. Simply merging "master" into "my_new_branch" will keep the branch up to date w.r.t master and avoid you having to rewind the remote branch.

To achieve this you can `reset` your "my_new_branch" with:

```
# (assuming no uncommitted changes that need preserving)
git reset --hard origin/my_new_branch
```

then merge and push:

```
git merge master
# resolve conflicts if needed.
git push origin my_new_branch
```

Comment: In general yes, but in this particular case (fixing up a too quick push) rebasing is the right thing to do.

Comment: @JanHudec: Why is it the right thing to do? The commits were originally made on a an old master and then updated with the changes to master. `merge` correctly preserves the actual history of what was done.

Comment: The logical history is much more useful if you ever need to find out why some change happened and fix a bug it introduced. Eventually it comes down to a matter of taste, but git community generally prefers logical history (both Linux and Git development require submitting feature branches factored to logically self-contained changesets rebased on current master or next).

Comment: Of course that only applies to one's own work. You rebase the changes you are cooking so as to make the individual patches make as much sense as possible to anybody who will review them. The order in which you changed individual lines is of no interest to anybody else, so you don't bother keeping that history. Than you finish it, rebase on master last time, test it, somebody reviews it and from this point on it's only merged. Because from this point on the order of merges becomes important, as if it now breaks, it's the merge that broke it, not the original change.

Comment: @JanHudec: I don't disagree with what you've said, you can rebase as much as you like (and massage your changes to be as neat and easy to review as possible) up to the point that you integrate into a published branch. Once you've done that, though, you should avoid rewriting commits that you've already pushed. In this case the asker wants to know what the correct workflow is. "happened to me several times" and "other than doing -f and forcing it" shows that the asker is looking for an alternative to the `rebase` / `push -f` workflow which, in any case, is probably a habit to avoid.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a habit to avoid. On the other hand he was asking "Then I realize.. Oops, I forgot to make sure my new branch", which suggests he meant to rebase before pushing (just forgot) and that nobody had time to use the branch yet. In which case fixing up with `rebase + push -f` is OK.